# Can I record an arrangement of another composer's music and upload it to YouTube?

Tags: copyright, music

I'm writing this orchestral arrangement of two of John Williams' compositions (Imperial March & Kylo Ren's theme). I will use a program to create a synthesized recording and want to upload it to youtube.  No commercial use of the work will be made.

Is this legal?

Answer (score 2):

No

This is a derivative of a copyright work and you need the permission of the copyright owner.

For music in most countries and the US in particular there is a statutory royalty scheme for performers so you can pay to do this.

Comment: Not disagreeing with this answer, but see this interesting article about posting a cover song video on YouTube. http://diymusician.cdbaby.com/youtube/posting-cover-songs-on-youtube-music-licensing-law-explained/